# How to add a script element in an iframe for jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a parent document and iframe with some JavaScript code to add a `script` element in an `iframe` bellow:

```
var script = window.document.createElement('script');
script.src = '/jquery.myPlugin.js';
window.frames['test'].document.head.appendChild(script);
```

How to rewrite this code for jQuery?

Comment: If the above works for the sortable plugin, why not just change the source file to where your jQuery's at ?

Comment: I edited the code above, look again.

Answer (score 1):

```
var $script = $('<script></script>').attr('src', '/jquery.myPlugin.js');
$('head', $('iframe[name=test]').get(0).contentWindow.document).append($script);
```